# Full Text Search not searching special character

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I am working on SQL Server 2008.
I have created full text index on a Table(Column) and I am trying to find.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TblName 
WHERE CONTAINS(ColName,'@#');
```

This is giving no results.

But I have a row in that column which contains value @# in field, so is this the default behavior of SQL Server Full Text Search, or am I doing something wrong and need to do something for this?

Answer (score 4):

I can't verify this right now, sorry, but IIRC you have to quote special characters because SQL Server assumes `@` and `#` are word delimiters

```
SELECT * FROM TblName WHERE CONTAINS(ColName,'"@#"')
```

Also see the [SQL Server FTS Engineering team blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20150916085337/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlfts/archive/2009/12/09/gotchas-on-searching-for-at-t-m-m-etc.aspx)